# How to initialize bean's property to its name from Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Is it possible to know bean's name from `@Bean`-annotated method and put it into this same bean's property, so that bean knows its own name?

If this way is impossible, then if there another way exist?

Comment: Why do you need for the bean to know its name?

Comment: My beans already have names. I wish they be the same as Spring's

Comment: Could you explain a situation where this matters? You can ask the `ApplicationContext/BeanFactory` for details on beans, but I fail to see the idea behind this.

Comment: I already fond an answer: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html

Comment: `Note that it is not usually recommended that an object depend on its bean name.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is the interface [BeanNameAware](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html) which should be implemented by your bean.